# AlchemyAPI get link for all entity

Tags: alchemyapi

In Alchemy API, is it possible to get links for all entity even though they are not disambiguated.

e.g.

```
<entity>
            <type>Country</type>
            <relevance>0.33</relevance>
            <count>2</count>
            <text>britain</text>
        </entity>
```

Even though `britain` is not ambigious, I want to get the linked data URL for dbpedia. More precisely, I want to get linked data for all entity

Answer (score 0):

AlchemyAPI only provides the linked data only for entities that have been disambiguated. So unfortunately what you want to do is not possible at this time.

From [the docs](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity/disamb.html):

> "Whenever an entity is successfully disambiguated, additional
>   information is returned in API responses. This includes the fully
>   resolved, disambiguated entity name, and if available, the entity's
>   website and geographic coordinates."